# Getting all pages data from restheart API

Tags: mongodb, rest, pagination, restheart

We know that RESTHEART API for Mongo provides facility to get data by pages and the maximum limit of pages is 1000.

Is there a way in Restheart or outside to get all pages data in single call?

I am just trying to avoid multiple rest calls using restheart for every page.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as it is not possible to retrieve an entire collection with a single mongodb driver call.

The limit of 1000 is imposed to bound the http request. With documents up to 10 megabytes or more of json it could even result in a huge payload!

You can however make concurrent requests for different pages to speed up the data retrieval...